# Difficulty in performing Addition in query calculation in Cognos Report Studio version 10.2.1

Tags: cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi, cognos-10

I am trying to perform **'Addition'** function for three columns horizontally in

> **Cognos Report Studio version 10.2.1**

For eg: I want the output to look like this

```
Col1  |Col2  |Col3  |Col4(Calculated Col) 
12    |16    |10    |38 
1     |5     |2     |8
```

All I am doing is selecting the column titles Col1, Col2, Col3 then right click and add calculation. It gives only one option that is to concatenate and the result is

```
Col1  |Col2  |Col3 |Col4 
12    |16    |10   |121610 
1     |5     |2    |152
```

This is not what I want. Can anyone guide? 
Pls note: I also used a cast function to change the datatype to integer just to be on a safer side.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can't you do it manually by creating an item with the sum and inserting it into the report?

Comment: I did that but still it only concatenates and not sum's up

Comment: @Markus I added a new Data Item, took 'Col1 + Col2 + Col3'. Do we have sum() function in Cognos? I couldn't find one.

Comment: From what I see, there MUST be something wrong with the type. Could you do a type case before you add?

Comment: @Marcus: I figured out, there was a data type mismatch. Thank you for your time and efforts. Appreciate it!

Comment: Would you consider answering your own question to formally close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to successfully perform addition to the columns by dragging a query calculation to the report and selecting the data items I wanted to perform addition. There was a datatype mismatch and hence was not able to perform any calculations.  Thank you Marcus for your time and efforts. Appreciate it!